# How to use attribute selectors for form fields in a SASS/SCSS list variable?

Tags: css, sass

Example:

```
$list: (
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="name"],
    input[type="email"],
    textarea,
    select[multiple]
) !default;

@each $value in $list {
    #{nth($value, 1)} {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Error (on build using Gulp):

```
Invalid CSS after "    input": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was '[type="text"],'
```

Escaping the `[` `]` like so `input\[type="text"\]` outputs no error yet does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the entries with quotations works:

```
$list: (
    'input[type="text"]',
    'input[type="name"]',
    'input[type="email"]',
    'textarea',
    'select[multiple]'
) !default;
```

Comment: For others' reference, once quoted, you don't need to use `@each` you can just interpolate it like `#{$list} { prop: val }`.